# Black screen when running xubuntu 13.10 after upgrade

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have a xubuntu v12 that I updated to v13.10.
Sice the upgrade I get the black screen at a startup. I can get to the console and login.
How can I run it in graphic mode?

I run it on Oracle Virtualbox.

```
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...done.
Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service  ...done.
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned;
 * Restoring resolver state...                                       [ OK ]
```

And it hangs on this.

Comment: What is the output of this command: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` Edit your question and post your output!

Answer (score 0):

Try with
**host+F1**
host is right control in my case, but it depend on your VirtualBox installation.
You gain the access to the terminal in this way.
When you entered, launch startx and the shell appear.
I know is not the solution, but is the point I reach till now since I have the same problem of you.